# Can't define __table_args__ on a child-class in a single-table inheritance setup

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've found that if `__table_args__` is present on a child class in a single-table inheritance setup, SQLAlchemy throws `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't place __table_args__ on an inherited class with no table`. At the same time it is possible to define a column with `index=True` on a child class, which alters the parent table the same way as `__table_args__`.

Here is my setup:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()


class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = sa.Column(sa.Text, nullable=False)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': type,
    }


class B(A):
    b = sa.Column(sa.Integer, index=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'b',
    }


class C(A):
    c = sa.Column(sa.Integer)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'c',
    }

    __table_args__ = (
        sa.Index('ix_test', c),
    )


engine = sa.engine.create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = sa.orm.Session(engine)

session.add_all([
    B()
])

session.commit()

print(session.query(A))
```

And it throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
   class C(A):
 File "/home/andrei/projects/my_project/.tox/dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/decla
rative/api.py", line 64, in __init__
   _as_declarative(cls, classname, cls.__dict__)
 File "/home/andrei/projects/my_project/.tox/dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/decla
rative/base.py", line 88, in _as_declarative
   _MapperConfig.setup_mapping(cls, classname, dict_)
 File "/home/andrei/projects/my_project/.tox/dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/decla
rative/base.py", line 103, in setup_mapping
   cfg_cls(cls_, classname, dict_)
 File "/home/andrei/projects/my_project/.tox/dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/decla
rative/base.py", line 133, in __init__
   self._setup_inheritance()
 File "/home/andrei/projects/my_project/.tox/dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/decla
rative/base.py", line 442, in _setup_inheritance
   "Can't place __table_args__ on an inherited class "
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't place __table_args__ on an inherited class with no table.
```

Do somebody know any workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indices can be placed outside of the table definition.

```
class C(A):
    c = sa.Column(sa.Integer)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'c',
    }

Index('ix_test', C.c)
```

Comment: That's a good workaround! Works with other constraints, like `CheckConstraint` too. Thank you very much, that saved a lot of time for me.

Comment: It works well when I want to create a composite unique constraints of a STI subclass, in which a column is later-mapped using `@declared_attr` too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I started to get this error after updating to SQLAlchemy 2.3.

If you can remove the table arguments, it will work (but may complain about other things, especially if two subclasses share a field name in common - this occurred for me with `__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}`.

In the end, the workaround was to specify the tablename on the subclasses explicitly, so as an example:

```
class Establishment(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'establishments'
    name = Column(String(32))

class Cafe(Establishment):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'cafe'}
    coffee_type = Column(String(32))

class Bar(Establishment):
    __tablename__ = 'establishments'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'bar'}
    alcohol_license_number = Column(String(40))
    bar_type = Column(Enum(BarType)) # defined elsewhere

class Restaurant(Establishment):
    __tablename__ = 'establishments'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'bar'}
    alcohol_license_number = Column(String(40))
    cuisine_list = Column(String(255))
```

A rough example but hopefully the idea makes sense - Restaurant and Bar both have a field to hold their alcohol license information, so we want these two to use the existing field in the table rather than conflict - now we have to specify the tablename since SQLAlchemy 2.3.

I know this example isn't exactly the same issue as the question (which was about Indexes), but it causes the same error and this solution should work in that case as well as this.

Comment: Accepted answer is better, because this method doesn't work for filtering. For example `Restaurant.query.all()` would return all Establishment instances instead of Restaurant only instances. Using `__tablename__ = None` fixes this issue, and its also documented in sqlalchemy's source code that this is the expected behavior for single table inheritance (see base.py where the exception `"Can't place __table_args__ on an inherited class"` is thrown)

Comment: I didn't have to use filtering, so I didn't think to check for that, but you are quite right. I will have to look at making a migration to using the accepted answer if that works for my use case (having all variations of my base class in a single table, but with some columns specific to the subclasses)