# SQLAlchemy can't set schema on an inherited class using __table_args__

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am not able to define a specific schema on an inherited class using `__table_args__` because SQLAlchemy throws `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't place __table_args__ on an inherited class with no table`

I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832848/cant-define-table-args-on-a-child-class-in-a-single-table-inheritance-setup) but this workaround does not work for defining the schema.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    full_name = sa.Column(sa.Text, nullable=False)


class Employee(User):

    company_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)

    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'foo'}
```

I'd like to declare `Employee` in schema `foo`

Do somebody know any workarounds?

Comment: Using the example [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance) I got [this code](https://pastebin.com/11QLcL1H) to work.

Comment: This code creates 2 tables linked by a relationship while I'd like only 1 table

Comment: So you want [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance.html#single-table-inheritance) then.

Comment: Not really, because I want `Employee` to be declared in a specific schema while `User` could be inherited by another class in another schema. Is it possible?

`User` > `Employee` in schema foo
`User` > `Artist` in schema bar

Comment: Okay, so you would want the `Employee` class to map to table `foo.user` and the `Artist` class to map to table `bar.user` and the two tables would be completely independent of one another?

Comment: Yes! But I'd like to have only 2 tables `foo.employee` and `bar.artist`. User is only here to define common attribute. Thx!

Comment: If you want `Employee` and `Artist` to use different table names (as well as different schemas) then you can just specify the `__tablename__` in each one and that should make the original error go away.

Comment: See also: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_mixins.html